# How to position window in gtkmm?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I'm trying to position a window in the bottom left corner of the screen when it opens, but I can't seem to find a way to do this (if it's even possible with just gtk). I found a way to center the window when it opens:

```
   set_position(Gtk::WIN_POS_CENTER);
```

Can I also use this trick to put the window in a corner? If not, is there a way to define the coordinates? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [this](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-move) might help or at least explain why opening a window in a specific position does not work.

Comment: @J.J.Hakala, that link actually also shows a way of doing it the OP could try. It may not be very robust, but it could work.